# CSS Media query works on desktop, not on iPhone

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've researched this question and tried to solve it on my own for hours, to no avail. Hoping one of you can help. I am using this media query for the style I want on a desktop browser:

```
@media all and (min-width: 320px) {}
```

And I'm using this media query for the style I want on mobile browser:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) and (min-width: 0px) {}
```

When I drag the desktop browser to less than 320px, the style changes accordingly. But when I bring up the website on a mobile browser, it displays the desktop style. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you setting initial bowser scale to 1?

Comment: Per Kai's suggestion below, I added the following media tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` Then when I loaded the site on a mobile browser, it was blank. I am using "max-width" in my media query, not "max-device-width" -- does that matter?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added that meta tag and then when I launched the site on iPhone, it was blank.